# What led to the creation of games in antiquity?

Tags: history

I am thinking to use games for my development of thinking on a particular concept/problem. I hope to use it to know on how games provide ways of thinking on other problems. I am also thinking on making these games naked, by knowing the general structure of all these games. If on how these games came to dawn or if a origin story of the first games are given, it will be helpful.

If any related book, article, passage, quote or even abstract game is suggested, it will be of greatest help.

But was there any theme or rationale behind early games?

Comment: Boredom ? Desire to have fun ? Aren't they something we human all look for ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_games

Comment: [History.se] might be a better place to ask about things like this, though you might have to narrow it down a little.

Answer (score 3):

Most of these games (running, jumping, chariot racing, fencing, javelin throwing etc.) were based on skills useful in war.

In fact, many considered these games a "civilized" form of war that allowed for the release of hostilities, without having the real thing.